# Free alternative to NI Real-Time Hypervisor?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-core, realtime

Is there an free alternative to National Instruments' NI Real-Time Hypervisor?  National Instruments provides both a [Windows](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/207302) and [Linux](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209016) versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking to accomplish, but it sounds like a mix of wanting a realtime OS, CPU shielding/affinity and a standard Linux or Windows userspace for development; all on standard hardware.

On the Linux side, this can definitely be accomplished with a realtime OS like [RedHat MRG Realtime (commercial)](http://www.redhat.com/mrg/realtime/), [Scientific Linux Realtime (Free)](https://serverfault.com/questions/268037/centos-5-realtime-patch/268085#268085) or [SuSE's realtime offering (commercial)](http://www.novell.com/products/realtime/).

That gets you a realtime kernel and OS. If you need to run specific tasks on a specific CPU or CPUs, you can use [CPU shielding techniques](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_management_utility/tutorial) to perhaps, create a group of CPUs for the OS and another group reserved for your realtime application execution.

Usually realtime and virtualization don't go hand-in-hand. The operating systems listed above provide extremely granular control over processes, scheduling, priority and interrupt handling.

Comment: Consider this target: - standard multicore PC. - Run a standard app that can manage a GUI, connections to DB, & Hi level communication with other devices using reserved RS232 /ethernet resources (like PC-SCADA-supervisor).- At the same time a CPU core works in a deterministic way(1 usec. resolution), controlling sennsor, digital/analog I/O, or motors, using reserved resources. Realtime and not realtime communicates through a virtual TCP/IP channel but are indipendent

Comment: This is possible, I believe. I'll use the example from my industry (high-frequency financial trading). You have a standard OS userland like RedHat or CentOS, but maybe an FPGA or high-end 10GbE network card processing a 15Mb/sec stream of financial market data. Multiple cores are dedicated to one task. Hardware interrupts are assigned to specific CPUs. It'll take some research, but the tools are out there. I also updated my post with a link to CPU shielding resources.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like [Hyper-v](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/default.aspx).  I don't see from the link that the hypervisor your link to does anything special that every type 1 hypervisor doesn't do.

Update - after reviewing it further it appears it contains support for some specialized hardware : "In addition, the Real-Time Hypervisor is specially designed to maintain the determinism of LabVIEW Real-Time programs"

Comment: From the words "real-time" in the name of the product, presumably it offers deterministic interrupt latency which is not something a general purpose OS offers.

Comment: Yes. Hard real time + hypervisor - I am surprised there even is such a product. kudos to the manufacturer.

Comment: You can run real time OSes in EVERY hypervisor AFAIK.  You simply have to adjust the scheduler to prioritize the guests

Comment: @janneb from the link "To ensure access to all Real-Time Hypervisor capabilities, use the LabVIEW 2009 Real-Time Module to program applications for the real-time side of hypervisor systems....In addition, the Real-Time Hypervisor is specially designed to maintain the determinism of LabVIEW Real-Time programs"  at best this means it has specialized drivers for access to the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that depends on what you want.

If what you need is a real-time OS to run some DAQ and/or control software, then yes, [Linux with the RT patchset](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) offers the usual real-time OS features.

If you want an alternative hypervisor for running Labview RT, then I don't know. It wouldn't surprise we if it refused to run on anything but their own hypervisor.

Answer (score 0):

VxWorks and LynuxWorks both have hypervisors based on hard-realtime schedulers, certified to go airplanes and such.  They're NOT cheap, but they do their job.