# Compiling realtime kernel from RHEL 6 MRG sources on CentOS 6

Tags: kernel, centos6, rhel6

I'm trying to compile kernel-rt-2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.src.rpm from [RHEL6 MRG source RPMs](http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/RHEMRG/SRPMS/) on Centos 6 x86_64 system.

It's first time I'm doing this, so I did research on how to do this properly. From what I found, I did:

```
rpm -ihv kernel-rt-2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.src.rpm 
cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
nano kernel-rt.spec 
rpmbuild -bb kernel-rt.spec 2> build-err.log | tee build-out.log
```

in kernel-rt.spec I've disbleed compilation of variants I don' need - ie compile only rt and firmware. Also defined not to build debuginfo.

After compilation finished, I've got in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/` two files:

```
kernel-rt-2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.x86_64.rpm
kernel-rt-devel-2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.x86_64.rpm
```

but when I tried to install kernel, I got error message:
$ sudo rpm -ihv kernel-rt-2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    kernel-rt-firmware >= 2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt is needed by kernel-rt-2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.x86_64

There was no folder ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch - where I would expect it to show up.

Also, I've tried `rpmbuild --rebuild kernel-rt-2.6.33.9-rt31.75.el6rt.src.rpm`, but got same results...

What am I doing wrong? 
I've seen [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/268037/centos-5-realtime-patch), but it suggests what I tried already and I want to build kernel myself, not use pre-built from SLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd still recommend using the [precompiled realtime kernels](https://serverfault.com/questions/268037/centos-5-realtime-patch) if you're not making any drastic driver changes or other optimizations, but if you need to build your own, do the following to generate the proper packages.

```
rpmbuild -ba --without debug kernel.spec
```

This builds your kernel.

```
rpmbuild -ba --target noarch --with firmware --without debug --without doc --without perftool --without perf kernel.spec
```

This builds the kernel-rt-firmware package.

Comment: yes i need to add drivers for my raid controller.
I've built it using command suggested by you - still didn't get kernel-rt-firmware package built...

Comment: Maybe try adding the `-with firmware` to the build macro in the first statement. I don't have a system to test with at the moment. Also, which RAID card drivers are you trying to add?

Comment: of course I tried --with firmware - it does not help.
LSI 9265-8i

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this myself, but there is a rt-firmware SRPM in the repo referenced in the question. Building that might provide the dependency.

Comment: It didn't compile properly to produce proper .rmp files. I didn't try if recent version compile, as I'm using precompiled RT kernels from Scientific Linux

Answer (score -1):

```
cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
rpmbuild -bb --without debug kernel-rt.spec --clean

cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
rpmbuild -bb --target noarch --with firmware --without debug --without doc --without perftool --without perf kernel-rt.spec --clean
```